# Getting tag name from xml

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have file with such structure:

```
<pwACL>
The gateway only supports upto 10 rules.
</pwACL>

<cmn53>
Batch Number
</cmn53>
```

I want to get tag name and data between tags. I tried to use BeatifulSoup HTMLParser library, but it automatically converts tag name to lowercase. I found that there was a possibility to use html5lib creating tree with beatifulsoup tree builder like this:

```
parser = html5lib.HTMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("beatifulsoup"))
```

but it seems like html5lib does not support beatifulsoup anymore. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

It's mentioned in [BeautisulSoup documentation - Other parsers problems](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems):

> Because HTML tags and attributes are case-insensitive, all three HTML
>   parsers convert tag and attribute names to lowercase. That is, the
>   markup `<TAG></TAG>` is converted to `<tag></tag>`. If you want to
>   preserve mixed-case or uppercase tags and attributes, you’ll need to
>   parse the document as XML.

[Parsing XML](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml):

> By default, Beautiful Soup parses documents as HTML. To parse a
>   document as XML, pass in “xml” as the second argument to the
>   BeautifulSoup constructor:
>
> ```
> soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")
> ```
>
> You’ll need to [have `lxml` installed](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parser-installation).

---

```
>>> markup = '''<pwACL>
... The gateway only supports upto 10 rules.
... </pwACL>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, 'xml')
>>> soup.find_all()
[<pwACL>\nThe gateway only supports upto 10 rules.\n</pwACL>]
```